# req.body undefined using MEAN Express 4.x and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm a total noob, and  looking to develop MEAN stack skills. I've got a basic node setup working and the basic GET route is working fine, but the POST and DELETE aren't passing data to mongo.

I've debugged to work out that the req.body is undefined, but I don't know why - i've :

checked that I'm using bodyParser
the routes are declared after the configs

here is the code app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var todos = require('./routes/todos');

// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

//Requires the mongoose connection 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todoApp', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/todos', todos);
app.use('/', routes);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

// start app ===============================================
// startup our app at http://localhost:3080
app.listen(port);               

// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

the Routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Todo = require('../models/Todo.js');

/* GET /todos listing. - THIS GUY IS WORKING OK */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(todos);
  });
});

/* POST /todos listings */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body); // THIS GUY IS UNDEFINED

Todo.create(req.query, function(err, post){
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
    });
});

module.exports = router
```

and the Schema/model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  completed: Boolean,
  note: String,
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
//note the declaration of the collection as the third argument to the model method

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', TodoSchema, 'todoApp');
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a POST to your route, you need to specify the content type header to be application/json.

```
POST -H Content-type: 'application/json' /post/route
```

What are you using to test your POST?

Comment: I'm using Postman - the Chrome plugin, but have noticed that it isnt sending json, but I can't work out why. Even when I select Raw and choose application/json, it still sends as txt/html which is frustrating. Also my req.headers.content.length = 0, which makes sense that the data isn't being sent - grrr

Comment: It's because you're still not adding the Content-type HEADER. Selecting application/json is just for the format of the text box where you put your input. Just under the URL is the area where you put your header information which needs to read:

Content-type: application/json